# How can i include files to use class in other included files?

Tags: php

I have 3 files in root folder

main.php:

```
require_once 'function.php';
load_layout($template="header"); // load header.php -- there are echo $session->user_id; code in header.php that not work
echo $session->user_id; //work
```

function.php:

```
require_once 'ses.php';
function load_layout($template="") {
    include ('header.php');
}
```

ses.php :

```
class Session {
    public $user_id = "1";
    public function userinfoss() {
        return $this->user_id;
    }
}

$session = new Session();
```

and header.php

```
require_once 'function.php';
echo $session->user_id; //not work in main.php loading but work if header.php run seprate
```

`echo $session->user_id;` work if `header.php` run seprately but it is included in `main.php` and `echo $session->user_id;` not work in `main.php` loading

How can I change my codes to display `echo $session->user_id;` in included files?

**update:**

I create a function in ses.php:

```
    class Session {
        public $user_id = "1";
        public function userinfoss() {
            return $this->user_id;
        }
    }

    $session = new Session();

    function testfun() {
    global $session;
    echo $session->user_id;
}
```

So call this function in header.php and worked
but Why `$session->user_id` not work ?

Comment: Where does the `load_layout` function come from?

Comment: Can you post the code of the `load_layout` function?

Comment: @user3409662 i edit question and add that function

Comment: When do you give `$session->user_id` a value?

Comment: @user3409662 there are other codes in class but i dont write that now i edit question and add value to user_id

Comment: @user3409662 i create function in ses.php this function work good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `main.php`, the first `require_once 'function.php';` will work, and it will call `require_once 'ses.php';`, which will make the `$session` variable available in `function.php` and in `main.php`;

When `header.php` gets included, however, the `require_once 'function.php';` it contains will not do anything (because `function.php` has already been included), and the `$session` variable will not be available in `header.php`.

---

Ideally, you should reorganize your code so that you don't have 2 files (`main.php` and `header.php`) that depend on the same file (`function.php`).

So, maybe you can replace:

```
require_once 'function.php'
load_layout($template="header");
```

in `main.php` by:

```
require_once 'header.php';
```

---

If you can't reorganize your code, then you can use a global variable for `$session`. Add:

```
global $session;
```

before

```
$session = new Session();
```

in `ses.php`.

You also need to add

```
global $session;
```

before

```
echo $session->user_id;
```

in `header.php`